# Firestore emulator - simulate loss of connectivity

Tags: google-cloud-firestore

I have an app with a real time listener setup to instantly pick up all updates on a collection. I also have some logic to pick missing documents afterwards in case my app loses its connectivity (in which case the listener would miss some documents).

I want to test this logic using the simulator, but how do I simulate the loss of connectivity? is there built-in function for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually the following [page](https://cloud.google.com/firestore/docs/manage-data/enable-offline#disable_and_enable_network_access) shows how to proceed in general, be it with the emulator or an actual Firestore instance:

```
firebase.firestore().disableNetwork()
    .then(() => {
        // Do offline actions
        // ...
    });

firebase.firestore().enableNetwork()
    .then(() => {
        // Do online actions
        // ...
    });
```